# How to implement one-to-one relationship while designing tables.\

Tags: mysql, database, datatable, relationship

I just need the brief explanation about how to implement one-to-one relationship while designing table

Comment: put a `parent_id` column in the child table

Comment: Both columns must be defined as UNIQUE and NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE master ( master_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                      {another columns} );

CREATE TABLE slave ( slave_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                     master_id INT NOT NULL,
                     UNIQUE (master_id),
                     FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES master (master_id),
                      {another columns} );
```

The row in `slave` which matches the row in `master` presence must be checked by client logic. Or it is possible that the row into `slave` is inserted during the row in `master` creation (by trigger), but this may contradict with some columns properties in `slave`.